# wpf modify single column to be comboboxcolumn

Tags: wpfdatagrid

I've made a significant edit to my original post.

Is there a way to modify a column so that it's a ComboBoxColumn without having to change the fact that the other columns will autogenerate?  Or is there a way to simply tack on another column that is a ComboBoxColumn?

I haven't supplied code because I'm just looking for a generic way of doing this.  If there isn't one then I'll look for alternatives afterwards.

I'm a complete newbie to this WPF stuff so any help would be appreciated.  If you need code let me know (it works but it's kinda messy).

Comment: As a general rule, the code will likely be necessary. I'm not a WPF guy so maybe some guru can answer without it, but generally that isn't the case.